# Visual Studio error when adding a library in the Form.Designer.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So basically I add this code to my Form1.Designer.cs:

```
this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

which requires adding `using System.Linq;` on top of `namespace WindowsFormsApp`. The program runs just fine, the only thing is that when I go back to the Form1.cs[Design] GUI part, Visual Studio returns me the following error: `To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved`.

I can ignore that and the program works just fine, but it kinda worry me. Is there maybe another way to add the `using System.Linq;` line without making VS get angry at you?

Comment: What is 'the following error' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to modify your designer generated code. Just put your line of code in your Forms constructor, after the line/region that is already there.

Comment: I already added the "this.comboBox.SelectedIndex = x;" to set default values for all comboBox controls. So you are suggesting to move all the manually written code inside the form constructor and just leave the designer with the only the automatically generated code by VS, right?

Comment: @ReduxInk Absolutely. Don't touch the designer generated code. That's only asking for trouble. That's why they are separated in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Visual Studio rewrites your file and removes the using. Try changing your code to

```
...System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, 30)...
```

That said. You shouldn't add code to the desinger file on any other place as in the default constructor (if present) after the call to `InitializeComponent()` or inside a `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)` function (if present).

And even then you should move the constructor or dispose function to your form1.cs file.

If you want to add items to your combobox do this via the property grid and let visual studio take core about writing the designer file or do it in the appropriate event handler (I would suggest either load or shown event).

The `InitializeComponent` wouldn't be the right place for modifing controls, since the next time you open the form in the designer the items are added to the combobox and get serialized during save unless your write

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    bool designMode = (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime);
    if(!designMode)
    {
        this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Cast<object>().ToArray());
    }
}
```